# Error when trying to create unit tests for wpf-project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

when i try to create unit tests using the unit test wizzard in visual studio 2008 the following error message is shown:

"The following error was encountered while reading module 'PresentationFramework': Could not resolve member reference: System.Windows.Automation.Provider.IToggleProvider::get_ToggleState"

I am able to create unit tests for all prjects that do not reference the 'PresentationFramework' module.

Any suggestions?

Best regards
Pascal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it-support said the problem might be related to a crash of VS some time ago. setup a new system with a fresh installation of visual studio solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing some dll references to your test suite, namely PresentationFramework.  You'll probably have to add PresentationCore and WindowsBase too.